How to parse the result of applicant__count in Model.objects.values("applicant", 'counter').annotate(Count("applicant")) to counter field?
I have a model with these fields although there are other fields but this is my MRE:
class Application(models.Model):     
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,    to_field='email')     
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)     
    counter = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, default=0)   

I want to find the number of applications in the table for each applicant and parse the value automatically to the counter field. In my views.py, I have been able to use:
model = Application.objects.values('applicant','counter').annotate(Count("applicant"))  

which returns correct values:
{'applicant': 'test@users.com', 'counter': 1, 'applicant__count': 2} {'applicant': 'second@user.org', 'counter': 1, 'applicant__count': 4}

But I am unable to extract the value of `applicant__count` and parse it directly to the counter field in models.py.
I tried using the update, update_or_create method but I'm not able to update the model. I also tried django signals pre_save and post_save but they keep incrementing every value. For example, one applicant can have many job applications but instead of returning the total number of job applications for an applicant, django signals increments all the applications in the table.
Is there any way to automatically save the result of  `applicant__count` to my counter field? I would really appreciate any help.

What is counter doing?

It's a model field to increment every job application.

But I want it to hold the total number of applications per user .. Not to increment all applications

storing aggregates is typically an antipattern: keeping the counts in sync is, strange as it may look, often close to impossible.

I would advise not to work with a counter field. Storing aggregates is often not a good idea: you can determine these when necessary.

I also tried django signals pre_save and post_save but they keep incrementing every value.

Exactly, that is the main reason not to store aggregates. It requires updating in all sorts of scenarios: if the target model is removed, updated, created, etc. If the queries are done in bulk, signals don't even run, making it often close to impossible to keep the counter in perfect sync.
You can remove the counter field:
from django.conf import settings


class Application(models.Model):
    applicant = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='email'
    )
    company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # counter = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, default=0)
and calculate it when necessary with .annotate(…) [Django-doc]: User.objects.annotate(counter=Count('application')).
Where here annotate the User object, annotating the application object means we lose the User object, and thus only have an email address that we need to link back to.
Storing the aggregate on the Application model also does not make much sense either: it would mean that the application is storing how many times the applicant of the Application has applied?


Note: It is normally better to make use of the settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL [Django-doc] to refer to the user model, than to use the User model [Django-doc] directly. For more information you can see the referencing the User model section of the documentation.


Thanks for your answer, I'm in  the process of trying it out and deadline for this task is today :(.

The reason for storing the count is to be able to call it up from the front end. We want to show something like total number of jobs applied

@16171413: well as said you can annotate the user/application model, so then you can render it, simply by using .count on the object. Storing the aggregate is not only a bad idea, but defining models in terms of what to show makes not much sense: models should not be concerned with what you show to the user, a model is about finding the (minimal) amount of data you need to store in the database. Rendering the data is what a view is concerned with.

ok  I have tried your solution (will upvote now). I am able to see the users but not the numbers associated. How can I get the number of applications only in views? Also our frontend is in Flutterflow which has little to no support for Python backend. That's why we thought to store the count in a table

@16171413: so how do you convert the data to the frontend exactly? Through a JSON blob?

Through Supabase. We are using Supabase (BAAS) as our backend

@16171413: well then you probably will have to do the JOIN and COUNT in the suabase.

Flutterflow syncs well with Supabase. Also Supabase (a postgre BAAS) works well with Django. So data goes from Django to Supabase and we fetch it from flutterflow frontend
